# Clickable custom array list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

How can I make this custom array list clickable to go to the others activities because I tried the intents but it doesn't work

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Names> namesArrayList = new ArrayList<Names>();

        namesArrayList.add(new Names(R.drawable.call_centre, "Call Centre"));
        namesArrayList.add(new Names(R.drawable.soco_academy_icon, "Academy"));

        NamesAdapter  NamesListAdapter = new NamesAdapter(this, namesArrayList);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List_View);

        list.setAdapter(NamesListAdapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [Intents are the way to go](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity). Could you post what you tried in order to give an idea on what you need help with?

Comment: Actually I tried to make this custom array list clickable to move to the other activities bus the problem is the android studio makes error incompatible types

Comment: I am using custom array to make it look more bueatiful if you have any advises to make beautiful list tell me please

Comment: Please post the error you got (take a screenshot if necessary and add it to your post)

Comment: @David Wasser The problem is I don't know which code should I add to OnItemClickListener to handle this custom array list

Answer (score 0):

In `onItemClick()` you can determine which item was clicked by doing this:

```
Name selectedName = NamesListAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with that.